# Web Deploy - DACPAC / XML Output

Tags: sql, xml, visual-studio, web-deployment

**I'm trying to deploy a web application. I can deploy the website portion just fine, however the SQL database won't deploy. The error I receive in VS2012 on my development machine is:**

*Error  24  Web deployment task failed. ((5/6/2014 1:36:23 PM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.)*

*(5/6/2014 1:36:23 PM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
The server experienced an issue processing the request. Contact the server administrator for more information.*

**On the web/sql server, the event logs give this:**

```
*User: 
Client IP: 192.168.254.122
Content-Type: application/msdeploy
Version: 9.0.0.0
MSDeploy.VersionMin: 7.1.600.0
MSDeploy.VersionMax: 9.0.1762.0
MSDeploy.Method: Sync
MSDeploy.RequestId: ea61751c-29cf-4764-8ad3-210cedc8fa53
MSDeploy.RequestCulture: en-US
MSDeploy.RequestUICulture: en-US
ServerVersion: 9.0.1762.0
Skip: objectName="^configProtectedData$"
Provider: auto, Path: 
A tracing deployment agent exception occurred that was propagated to the client. Request ID 'ea61751c-29cf-4764-8ad3-210cedc8fa53'. Request Timestamp: '5/6/2014 1:36:13 PM'. Error Details:
ERROR_CANNOT_PROCESS_DACPAC_OUTPUT Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentDetailedException: The output received from executing dacpac in a seperate process was not valid xml.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_CANNOT_PROCESS_DACPAC_OUTPUT. ---> 

        System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 19, position 10.
           at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
           at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()
           at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
           at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadDocSequence(XmlDocument parentDoc)
           at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
           at System.Xml.XmlDocument.LoadXml(String xml)
           at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.SqlDacPacProvider.ProcessExeOutput()
           --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
           at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.SqlDacPacProvider.ProcessExeOutput()
           at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.SqlDacPacProvider.RunExecutableAsync(String exeName, String arguments, Int32 waitInterval, Int32 retryAttempts)
           at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.SqlDacPacProvider.Add(DeploymentObject source, Boolean whatIf)
           at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.Add(DeploymentObject source, DeploymentSyncContext syncContext)
           at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.HandleAdd(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
           at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildren(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
           at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
           at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.ProcessSync(DeploymentObject destinationObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
           at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncToInternal(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions, PayloadTable payloadTable, ContentRootTable contentRootTable, Nullable`1 syncPassId, String syncSessionId)
           at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleSync(DeploymentAgentAsyncData asyncData, Nullable`1 passId)
           at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleRequestWorker(DeploymentAgentAsyncData asyncData)
           at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleRequest(DeploymentAgentAsyncData asyncData)*
```

**When I "test connection" for the SQL Database from VS2012 it works just fine, so I know it's not a connection/authentication issue. It looks like the dacpac file is using the wrong version of XML maybe? If nobody has a way to fix the error given, is there a way for me to manually deploy the database?**

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, and it ended up being a permissions issue.

The user only had db_datareader, db_datawriter, and execute.

I needed to give the SSDT user db_owner, then I was able to get past this error.