# Web deployment task failed (ERROR_CANNOT_PROCESS_DACPAC_OUTPUT)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Web deployment task failed.

> The output received from executing dacpac in a separate process was not valid xml.
>   Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_CANNOT_PROCESS_DACPAC_OUTPUT

I am trying to publish my website which is developed using `ASP.NET` MVC with `Code First Entity FrameWork` on a Windows 2008 R2 server(IIS).

But I couldn't publish because of this error shown above.
Please help me.

Comment: Permission issue? As per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23502909/web-deploy-dacpac-xml-output

Comment: How do we check the permissions, I am using windows authentication. I am confused @Macilquham

Comment: Are you including the publishing a database in your deployment?

Comment: you need to see what the output is and see why it is invalid.